# Where Does a PHP Constant with a Leading Backslash End Up?

Tags: php, namespaces

If you want to define a namespaced constant in PHP, you need to use the full path.

```
define('theNamespace\CONSTANT_NAME',42);
echo theNamespace\CONSTANT_NAME, "\n";
```

If you accidentally include a leading backslash, PHP **will not** define the constant.

```
define('\theNamespace\CONSTANT_NAME',42);
echo theNamespace\CONSTANT_NAME, "\n";
#PHP Fatal error:  Undefined constant 'theNamespace\CONSTANT_NAME'
```

However, the `define` function doesn't complain about the later usage.  Does this `\theNamespace\CONSTANT_NAME` constant end up anywhere accessible via PHP, or is the value just lost in the ether somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets into the defined constants array. My guess is there is no other way to look it up other than calling [get_defined_constants()](https://www.php.net/get_defined_constants)

```
define('\theNamespace\CONSTANT_NAME',42);
echo get_defined_constants()['\theNamespace\CONSTANT_NAME'];
```